# Is it possible to Install Android Studio on ChromeBook?

Tags: android, android-studio, chromebook

For my understanding, Chrome Book is more than just a browser, so I am wondering, if it is possible to install Android Studio on Chrome Book.

Credit to @navigaid

As of now, Android Studio is ChromeBook is in preview. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/studio

As of today August 21, 2019 with Android Studio 3.5, you can run Android studio on ChromeBook,
https://developer.android.com/studio/install#chrome-os

```
System requirements for Chrome OS according to the official site 

8 GB RAM or more recommended

4 GB of available disk space minimum

1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

Intel i5 or higher (U series or higher) recommended
```

Recommended devices:

```
Acer: Chromebook 13/Spin 13, Chromebox CXI3

Lenovo: Yoga C630 Chromebook

HP: Chromebook x360 14, Chromebox G2

Dell: Inspiron Chromebook 14

ASUS: Chromebox 3

ViewSonic: NMP660 Chromebox

CTL: Chromebox CBx1
```

Comment: This links may helpful for you. http://tomwwolf.com/2013/11/20/howto-android-development-on-chromebook/ http://tamingandroidcode.blogspot.in/2013/12/running-android-studio-on-chromebook.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

As of this writing, PixelBook has already been able to run Linux applications including Android Studio. Hopefully this feature will eventually roll out to other high end Chrome OS devices in the near future.

source:  [Preview Android Studio on Chromebooks](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/studio)

Answer (score 15):

You can, but you are required to install additional linux flavor on your Chromebook i.e, [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) project. It allows an easy method of doing that.

remember that **ChromeOS** runs on Linux, and you are basically adding another Linux flavor to your Chromebook.

Some useful links,

- [Crouton Github Page](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)
- [Crouton Cookbook](http://tomwwolf.com/chromebook-14-compedium/chromebook-crouton-cookbook/)
- [Crouton Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/109120069102230291151)
- [Crouton Script, From an SD Card](http://craigerrington.com/blog/crouton-script-from-sd-card/)
- [How to Install Ubuntu Linux on Your Chromebook with Crouton](http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/)
- [Howto: Android Development on Chromebook](http://tomwwolf.com/2013/11/20/howto-android-development-on-chromebook/)

or you may follow [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MJZYllAj_o-erv4WF2CKdjtHjT6Wee4t4mj6SlDRG8c/edit) step by step guide on how to use **Crouton** to Install an Ubuntu Chroot on Chromebook.

[source](http://tamingandroidcode.blogspot.com/2013/12/running-android-studio-on-chromebook.html)