# Android Development Studio @ ASUS Chromebook Flip

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I just signed up for [Nanodegree Programs for Jobs in Technology](https://www.udacity.com/nanodegrees) and also purchased [ASUS Chromebook Flip C100PA](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/ASUS_Chromebook_Flip_C100PA/). I already enabled `Chromebook Developer mode` and switched `Chrome OS` to `dev` channel as well, and now I'm trying to figure out how to install Android Developer Studio...

Is there an *easy* way to do it?

I found following: [Howto: Android Development on Chromebook | Tom W Wolf](https://tomwwolf.com/2013/11/20/howto-android-development-on-chromebook/), back from Nov 20, 2013 and I'm hoping maybe something changed and made it easier)

Comment: No there isn't. you have to add linux flavor. Please search extensively before posting a new question to see whether it is already asked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346595/is-it-possible-to-install-android-studio-on-chromebook

Comment: Beyond the OS issue, the Flip has an ARM CPU. There is no ARM support for running Android Studio on any OS, let alone Chrome OS.

Comment: oh well( one would think android development studio should run on google chrome os, i guess not... well not on arm anyways(